# Please allow Stack Overflow for Teams to specify or use the old question upvote value

Tags: support, status-deferred, questions, asking-questions, stack-overflow-for-teams

I am currently one of the administrators of a private team based on Stack Overflow for Teams. Like most of the members of Stack Exchange Q&A communities I have seen the question upvote increased from 5 to 10, **including on private communities**.

I do not think this is OK, at least for the community I am trying to develop:

- the main message for promoting the community is "getting answers to your questions". It is important to emphasize the answers part
- based on experience, I would say that, on average, to write a decent question in the community takes about 2-5 times less effort than writing an answer. As a principle, I believe that the reward should approximately be proportional to the effort spent
- those who have the knowledge (know-how) and are also willing to spend an effort providing good answers are only a fraction of the entire community. I really want to reward more this effort
- **[most important]** Some of our members has explicitly said that they would like real-life incentives to spend effort in the community. Not exactly the SE spirit, but this is life. Our company already provides some incentives (e.g. vouchers) based on side activities (e.g. write an article for the tech blog, present something at a tech conference) and I am willing to include the platform in this incentives program.

The simplest model to provide incentives is to use the reputation (e.g. highest reputation earned in current month, TOP 3). However, since asking a question is way simpler that answer it, there is a big chance that I fail to reward the bigger effort.

**So, please allow Stack Overflow for Teams to specify or use the old question upvote value (5p / upvote).**

Comment: The one thing I would note is questions are far less likely to get any upvotes at all, in the event they do the answer very often will receive more votes than the question, as it should be. I can see the logic of making changes so that even if votes score the same, answers will still generate more score than questions. That being said, it seems very weird to not allow private teams to set their own custom scoring.

Comment: @Matthew - I know that on public stack there is this issue of questions getting less votes. However, the private one have the advantage that it is easier to train the users to also appreciate the questions. I am not really into configuring the points (it is hard to code), but at least not to be affected by the "public experiments".

Comment: I completely agree with respect to teams, it seems odd they wouldn't allow you to set custom vote values, let alone what it used to be just to avoid the issues you've mentioned.

Comment: I don't think it was appropriate to change SO for Teams when the public site was changed. As paying customer a change of that magnitude should have been announced well in advance and an option to opt out provided.

Comment: If your plan is to use the platform to provide incentives wouldn't you want more information than just reputation such as how many questions have been asked/answered and what the average score for the posts was? I would think that you would want to treat rewards differently for a single well-received answer/question than someone who posts a lot of answers/questions that overall get a lot of attention. Afterall is it more important to help with questions in areas that don't receive a lot of traffic or a question that gets a lot of votes because of more traffic but less overall use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, Teams reflects any reputation changes that we make to Stack Overflow. We have plans to add configurable point values, but it's currently not slated until late next year.

Comment: Is is possible to use a SEDE query to calculate points using custom rewards values?

Comment: @James Teams information is not included in SEDE, but you could build something via the Teams API.